# Docker build fio with librbd

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to build a docker image of fio with librbd so that I can set the ioengine=rbd. I am building for arch aarch64. When I run fio with ioengine=rbd I get an error saying unable to load librbd. Any help here really appreciated.

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
From alpine

RUN apk add --update-cache fio librbd --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

**I build and push my docker image:**

```
$ sudo docker build . -t manjo8/fio
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : From alpine
 ---> bb3de5531c18
Step 2/2 : RUN apk add --update-cache fio librbd --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
 ---> Running in 68e44788feb0
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/19) Installing libaio (0.3.112-r1)
(2/19) Installing numactl (2.0.14-r0)
(3/19) Installing fio (3.28-r1)
(4/19) Installing libblkid (2.37.2-r0)
(5/19) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r1)
(6/19) Installing libgcc (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(7/19) Installing xz-libs (5.2.5-r0)
(8/19) Installing boost1.76-iostreams (1.76.0-r0)
(9/19) Installing boost1.76-thread (1.76.0-r0)
(10/19) Installing libstdc++ (10.3.1_git20210424-r2)
(11/19) Installing fmt (7.1.3-r1)
(12/19) Installing eudev-libs (3.2.10-r0)
(13/19) Installing librados (16.2.6-r1)
(14/19) Installing argon2-libs (20190702-r1)
(15/19) Installing device-mapper-libs (2.02.187-r1)
(16/19) Installing json-c (0.15-r1)
(17/19) Installing libuuid (2.37.2-r0)
(18/19) Installing cryptsetup-libs (2.3.6-r0)
(19/19) Installing librbd (16.2.6-r6)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r3.trigger
OK: 26 MiB in 33 packages
Removing intermediate container 68e44788feb0
 ---> 1534fb8d9308
Successfully built 1534fb8d9308
Successfully tagged manjo8/fio:latest
```

**When I run the docker image I get an error saying its unable to load librdb.**

```
fio-5c6dc65894-bh7dt
fio: file:ioengines.c:127, func=dlopen, error=Error loading shared library rbd: No such file or directory
fio: engine rbd not loadable
fio: failed to load engine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [build log for fio](https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86/community/fio/fio-3.28-r1.log), it says that it is building fio without support for Rados Block Device engine:

```
Rados Block Device engine     no
```

So, the only thing to do is to build it from source. Using the build script from alpine, plus some googling for how to build fio with rbd support, I came up with this:

```
From alpine

ENV fio_version=3.28

RUN set -vuo pipefail \
 && apk add --no-cache libaio-dev librados librbd \
 && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps linux-headers zlib-dev coreutils gcc make musl-dev ceph-dev \
 && cd /tmp \
 && wget https://github.com/axboe/fio/archive/fio-$fio_version.tar.gz \
 && tar -xzf fio-$fio_version.tar.gz \
 && rm /tmp/fio-$fio_version.tar.gz \
 && cd /tmp/fio-fio-$fio_version \
 && ./configure  \
     --prefix=/usr \
     --disable-native \
 && make -j \
 && make install \
 && rm -rf /tmp/fio-fio-$fio_version \
 && apk del --no-network .build-deps
```

I'm only able to test it in a limited way, given that I don't have a ceph cluster, but I'm able to get past the error you were having.

I also spent some effort optimizing the build so it wouldn't waste space by including build-time dependencies into the image. (This is the `--virtual .build-deps` and `apk del .build-deps` stages you see above.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! that worked, I was able to do a quick test on a ceph cluster. I will post some details here pretty soon.   "fio version" : "fio-3.28",
  "timestamp" : 1638455410,
  "timestamp_ms" : 1638455410096,
  "time" : "Thu Dec  2 14:30:10 2021",
  "global options" : {
    "directory" : "/scratch/fio-8587ff97-d74dt",
    "ioengine" : "rbd",
    "direct" : "1",
    "size" : "10G",
    "runtime" : "180",
    "name" : "fio-rand-rw"

Comment: Thanks a ton for you help with fio builds, but I am running into a bit of a configuration issue which I trying to work out with the rook-ceph team at the moment. https://github.com/rook/rook/discussions/9300 Looks like I am pretty close with a bit of a nudge.